# on deploying my backend on render.com facing error

Tags: reactjs, web-services, deployment, mern, render.com

I am deploying my basic project of CRUD notes on render.com which is a MERN project. But I am getting error again and again, dont know why.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrYU1.png)
dont know why
i am pasting some lines of error
May 18 11:29:15 PM  npm ERR! server@1.0.0 build: `npm run build`
May 18 11:29:15 PM  npm ERR! Exit status 137
May 18 11:29:15 PM  npm ERR!
May 18 11:29:15 PM  npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 build script.
May 18 11:29:15 PM  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
May 18 11:29:15 PM
May 18 11:29:15 PM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
May 18 11:29:15 PM  npm ERR!     /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2023-05-18T17_59_15_893Z-debug.log
May 18 11:29:15 PM  ==> Build failed

I will provide code also if needed.

I am stucked i want to get solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.